# How to remove Shipping Calculator on Paypal Checkout Page

Tags: paypal

I want to remove the Shipping and Handling Calculator that shows up on the Paypal Checkout page. What happens is that when a customer enters his zip code then tax and shipping is calculated by Paypal and this is added to the total that was sent by the our website.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for removing the shipping calculator on the checkout page then you can remove it from your PayPal account by going to **Profile - > My selling Tools --> Shipping Calculator** . Delete all the shipping methods that you see there .

Once its from there , you will no longer see them on checkout page .